# Prepositions usage, "in" or "on" the user profile

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

What preposition should be used in this sentence:

The information about gender is given "in/on/at" the user's profile.

Comment: More commonly, *in*. But this question really should be asked on our sister site [ELL.se], so if you want a rationale for that choice, or any other details or follow-up questions, please ask there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose "in," because in this case the profile is a collection of information.

Comment: Upvoting, because a previous uncommented downvote seemed unreasonable. "In" is correct: the user's profile is indeed a collection of information, within which can be found the user's gender.